# What insights can I demonstrate in the difference between the two chart shapes?

Tags: data-visualization

[image: Gas usage]

When I see the billing period data, I see I'm progressively using more gas each period. But when I look at data by monthly I'm using less gas.

Comment: Results are  distorted by the fact that data are seriously incomplete for November. and partially incomplete for February. So, only the graph on the left makes complete sense without adjustments for those facts and indeed the graph 
 on the right seems useless except for comparing December and January. Not really a strong statistical issue here, but more a matter of looking at the details behind the data.

Comment: Although this is arguably on-topic, I can't see it being of use to anyone else in the future. It doesn't illustrate any major point. It's not really about chart shapes: it's about very specific details in a very small dataset.

Comment: @NickCox I see your point about it being specific, but I am voting to leave it open (and I wrote an answer). Maybe a different title would make it somewhat more useful?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, the data is complete over the billing period which is why November is only partial. I just found it interesting that by simply visualising the same data and same attribute (time) I get a completely different picture. Yes this is natural gas heating/cooking the home. I reason I become curious is because my bill amounts were rising but the monthly graph shows usage decreasing and I figured the slide adjustment of around 6 days could not skew the chart that much, but it really does. Perhaps a good example of how data could be misinterpreted!!??

Comment: In fact the closer one looks, the worse it gets. One bar chart has axes starting at 0, but the other at 3100. Finally, although only physicists and pedants may care, it should be kWh not kwh.

Answer (score 0):

@Nick Cox's first comment is completely correct. But you can get around this by using the data differently. I can see several possibilities:

First, you could have your second plot but, rather than the sum over the month, you could look at the average per day. That would deal directly with the problem Nick identifies.

Second, if you have the data for each day (which it seems like you do) you could graph that, along with a smooth curve.

Third, if your goal is to model gas usage, rather than just display it, you could explore regression models and include relevant covariates (which would depend on whether the gas you are talking about is gasoline for a car, gas to heat your home, gas for cooking or something else).

Comment: British user, so presume (domestic consumption of) natural gas, not gasoline (petrol).